# Blogdown displays images, but not plots after rendering on new posts (old posts still work and render correctly)

Tags: blogdown

I removed the ".gitignore" from the static folder in Hugo theme, it did not change the result. I tried to "[markup.goldmark.renderer] unsafe= true" to the "config.toml", it dit not work. If I knit the html-document, it displays both images and plots.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example (ideally, as a Github repo).

Comment: Thanks for answering Yihui! I do not have a Github profile, since I am very new to programming in general and blogdown in particular. Could you please tell me what a reproducible example means? I did not change anything in config or somewhere else, I only updated to macOS Catalina and updated all packages in R studio. I still have "index_files" and "figure-html" with produce plots in it. But apparently there is no connection to it for new posts. If the only way to solve this problem is to create the Github profile, then I will do so.

Comment: I found the workaround this problem, still (unfortunately) don't get, what is wrong. Namely, adding the option: "fig.path = "static" into the first code-chunk: knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.path = "static"), solved the problem....but should I add this now for all my R-markdown documents?

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue. The static plot like from ggplot2 is being rendered after adding.

```
fig.path = "static" into the first code-chunk: knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.path = "static"
```

But the interactive plots from plotly and table with dt::datatable and rmarkdown::paged_table() are not being rendered.